# Error testing DAL in slick scala

Tags: scala, slick, scalatest

Pretty new to scala and play and I have been assigned a task to test someone else app,which is running fine btw.Please check if my tests are right and what is the error.

This is employeeEntry.scala file in models

```
 package models

import models.database.Employee
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
import play.api.db.slick._
import play.api.Play.current


case class EmployeeEntry(eid :Int, ename: String, eadd: String, emob: String)

object Employee {

val DBemp = TableQuery[Employee]


def savedat(value: EmployeeEntry):Long = {
    DB.withSession { implicit session =>
       DBemp+=EmployeeEntry(eid=value.eid,ename=value.ename,eadd=value.eadd,emob=value.emob)
    }}

/*val query = for (c <- Employee) yield c.ename 
    val result = DB.withSession {
                                 implicit session =>
                                 query.list // <- takes session implicitly
                                }*/
        //val query = for (c <- Employee) yield c.ename
   def getPersonList: List[EmployeeEntry] = DB.withSession { implicit session =>      DBemp.list }

  def Update: Int = DB.withSession { implicit session =>
 (DBemp filter (_.eid === 1) map (s => (s.ename,s.eadd))) update ("test","khair")}

  def delet :Int =DB.withSession {
  implicit session => (DBemp filter (_.eid === 1)).delete
}






 }
```

And this is file Employee.scala in models/database

```
 package models.database

 import models._
 import models.EmployeeEntry
 import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
 import scala.slick.lifted._

 class Employee(tag:Tag) extends Table[EmployeeEntry](tag,"employee") 
 {



   //val a = "hello"
  def eid = column[Int]("eid", O.PrimaryKey)
  def ename = column[String]("name", O.DBType("VARCHAR(50)"))
  def emob = column[String]("emob",O.DBType("VARCHAR(10)"))
  def eadd =column[String]("eadd",O.DBType("VARCHAR(100)"))
  def * = (eid, ename, emob, eadd) <> (EmployeeEntry.tupled, EmployeeEntry.unapply)


 }
```

Finally this is my test I am running,which is failing :

```
 import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
 import play.api.db.slick._
 import play.api.Play.current



 import org.scalatest.FunSpec
 import org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers
 import models.database.Employee
 import scala.slick.lifted._ 
 import models._
 import models.EmployeeEntry
 //import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._


 class databasetest extends FunSpec with ShouldMatchers{


   describe("this is to check database layer"){ 

       it("can save a row"){

            val a = EmployeeEntry(1006,"udit","schd","90909090")
            Employee.savedat(a) should be (1)


      }     


     it("getpersonlist"){



            Employee.getPersonList.size should be (1)


    }


     }

  }
```

The test is failing and error is

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
  at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
  at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:71)
  at models.Employee$.getPersonList(EmployeeEntry.scala:27)
  at databasetest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply$mcV$sp(databasetest.scala:39)
  at databasetest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(databasetest.scala:39)
  at databasetest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(databasetest.scala:39)
  at org.scalatest.Transformer$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Transformer.scala:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default play provides spec2 testing framework.so no need to add scalatest framework for unit testing.For database access layer testing required  a connection with database so start a fake application.(this is not running code, just an idea to write unit test)
for more detail take a look play doc : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithSpecs2

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

import models.database.Employee
import models._
import models.EmployeeEntry
import play.api.test.FakeApplication
import play.api.test.Helpers.running
import play.api.Play.current


class databasetest extends Specification {

 "database layer" should {
     "save a row" in {
        running(FakeApplication()) {
           val a = EmployeeEntry(1006,"udit","schd","90909090")
           Employee.savedat(a) must be equalTo (1)
         }
       }
    "get list" in {
         running(FakeApplication()) {
           Employee.getPersonList.size must be equalTo (1)
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,was reading play frameworks doc and saw this : _Play frequently requires a running Application as context: it is usually provided from play.api.Play.current_


.What does **running application** mean here ?

Comment: running application means play framework initialize all require component. Here need of connection with database so running application  creates a connection with database.